# Android How to Remove ImageView from RelativeLayout

Tags: android, android-imageview

I am trying to figure out what is the proper way to remove an ImageView from a RelativeLayout is? I have tried

```
relativeLayout.removeView(someImageView)
```

but this causes some issues on certain phones. See this other post here for stacktrace. [Removing ImageView causes crash on certain phones](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12614272/removing-imageview-causes-crash-on-certain-phones)

I really don't want to do the solution where you just make it appear gone because that is basically leaking that ImageView in memory right?

```
someImageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Any other ideas would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you remove a view from a relative layout, you must reset the relative layout parameters for all other views which are dependent on the view that you are removing. Otherwise, these other views will reference your removed view and throw a NPE.

Consider using another root layout design (like `LinearLayout`) if you want to achieve this without using `View.GONE`

Comment: So currently everything that is being placed into the RelativeLayout is being placed based on exact calculated pixels. None of them are referencing each other, at least I am not explicitly do this.

Comment: How to reset the relative layout params in this case.